# Pushing data back to Auth0 database

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, auth0, auth0-connection

Forgive the basic question but I'm not a developer or sysAdmin.  I just play one on TV.

I have an auth0 application that has a database and multiple social logins enabled.

I use that application to allow user to log into 3 platforms (discourse, rocket.chat, and wordpress).

If a user logs into one platform (e.g. discourse) and makes a change to some aspect of their profile (e.g. their avatar), is there a way to sync those changes back to the Auth0 database so they are reflected when they visit the other platforms?

Each of the platforms is connected to auth0 using oAuth2

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain each of those individual applications would need to support writing user profile updates back to Auth0 via the user patch endpoint of the [Auth0 Management API](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2). Assuming they do not support that functionality you would likely need custom code that syncs the data for you.